# extjs filter editor

Tags: extjs

does extJS have any kind of visual filtering tool for its grids.

there are three sample criterias in the next line which are added by the user, and an x button to remove the criteria.

*Sample Filter:*

[Business Unit=Accounting-x]      [Name like 'Jo*'-x]     [Age between 25-33-x]

**Personnel Grid** (displaying the filtered data)

*1 33 Josh Accounting*

*2 35 John Accounting*
[alt text http://img189.imageshack.us/img189/9879/searchresultsn.jpg](http://img189.imageshack.us/img189/9879/searchresultsn.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I used Ext, but if I remember correctly, you can access the store property of the grid control. This gives you an Ext.data.Store which has a filter method that can take either a String or a RegEx. You can then update the grid control (I don't remember if this is required or not, but I seem to remember it being required in Ext 2.1).

Look at the API documentation for Ext.data.store.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/examples/grid-filtering/grid-filter-local.html

Comment: not it, take a look at the attached picture, its not in English, but you'll get the idea (cell phone search results)

Comment: Well, you didn't post the picture originally. There's nothing like that in Ext, you'll have to write it yourself.  The link I provided shows one implementation of custom grid filtering, perhaps that code can help you if you look at how its done.

Comment: yeah brian, I could not find any sample like that (at least in english).
I guess a picture really is worth a thousand words sometimes.